# Sort Splitted words Respectively to another splitted words

Tags: javascript, sorting, split, strsplit

I am trying to sort some words that i provide with another splitted words the input i give is

`a = "excel|side|home|door"`
`b = "|"`
`c = "or|de|el"`

and the code i am using is as

```
data.result = a.split(b)?.filter(x=>c.split(b).some(y => x.includes(y))).join(b);
```

that gives the output as `excel|side|door` which is respective/order as ‘a’ input but i want it ti return b as a order of ‘a’ instead of returning `excel|side|door` i want it to return as `el|de|or`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flatMap` to combine `filter` and `map` here. In addition, use `Array#find` to get the actual matching element rather than just checking for existence.

```js
let a = "excel|side|home|door", b = "|", c = "or|de|el";
let res = a.split(b)?.flatMap(x=>c.split(b).find(y => x.includes(y))||[]).join(b)
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort by the index they are found in `a`:

```js
let a = "excel|side|home|door", b = "|", c = "or|de|el";

console.log(c.split(b).sort((x, y) => a.indexOf(x) - a.indexOf(y)).join(b));
```